# Best practice to write validation methods in angularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, coding-style, refactoring

In java, we have exception handling. Where we can write common validator methods which handles validation and throw proper exception message.

Same way, how to manage validator methods which are common to more than one controller in angularJS project.

I have a common div in all html pages which displays error messages. Error object is defined in each controller.

In controller,

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function (CommonValidatorService) {
      $scope.errorMessage = '';           
      CommonValidatorService.validateXXX();
      CommonValidatorService.validateYYYY();
})
```

Above validators generate error messages which needs to be displayed on view page.

What to use for CommonValidatorService? ie Service OR factory?

What is best way to handle the validation methods common to more than one controller in angularJS.

Any small example(not in deep/pseudo code) would be great.

Thank you !!!

Comment: the error handling using exception is not the correct way, when you are doing it on UI side, because here you need to show it on screen.. read about angular way of error handling `using $errors` and try to stick to that

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this way:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl' function ($rootScope) {
try{ 
     // your code
 }
 catch (err) { 
     $rootScope.errorMessage = err.message;           
  }
});
```

Moreover Throw a common Error from the Service if you want and it will update the $rootScope variable and bind it with the HTML.

You can also try **ng-pattern** why would some one make a service for validation error , Angular is for client side Development ,Don't mix Java server side coding way in this I would say.